# How to pass Authorization Token to my backend service through WSO2 (API Manager) version 4.1.0?

Tags: api, wso2, token, wso2-api-manager

I need to pass Authorization Token from API Manager (WSO2) to my Backend using policies like Header policy but it works for me only using cURL but not with UI.

curl -k  -X 'GET' 
'https://localhost:8243/test/1.0.0/support/get/55' 
-H 'accept: /' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer gatewayToken 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer BackendToken'

[Screenshot of the result after adding Header policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3gtF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the authorization header is dropped from the API gateway after validating the request. So you can't send the same header here with multiple values. If you want to send a custom header in the UI, you can do this as follows.

1. In the API publisher click on the API and go to the API configuration section.
2. Click on the resource tab and select a HTTP method.
3. Under parameters, you can add a header. Then from the Swagger UI, you can set this header when trying out the request.

[image]

Using API policies in API Manager 4.1.0, you can add AddHeader policy and send any static headers to the backend services.

Comment: The token is fixed so i wouldn't like the user to pass every time the token ,i would like to be passed automatically from the API publisher .

Comment: In that case you can use API policies and Authorization header from there.

Comment: This is what i did actually ,but the problem that API Manager don't read the header that i have passed through the applied  policies .

Comment: I tried this in APIM v4.1 and it is working fine. I could add a header from the API policies.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with a custom Operation Policy and adding that to the inflow of the API.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TokenExchange">
    <property name="Custom" expression="get-property('transport', 'Custom')"/>
    <property name="Authorization" expression="get-property('Custom')" scope="transport"/>
    <property name="Custom" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
</sequence>
```

Here, you have to send the backend token with a different header value (Custom) and gateway will automatically forward it to the backend under the Authorization header.

You can refer [1] to get an idea about this flow. Since the mediation sequences are replaced with Operation policies in APIM 4.1.0, you will have to refer the doc [1] and create and apply the Operation policy accordingly.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/passing-a-custom-authorization-token-to-the-backend/#passing-a-custom-authorization-token-to-the-backend

Comment: I did it, but it works only with cURL but if i do it using the API Devportal it didn't work as i ask how to pass the token from API Devportal !

Comment: Did you configure a new header (Eg: Custom) for the API resource from the publisher portal and deploy it? If you have added it like that, that field should appear in the devportal tryout for you to pass a value

Comment: I have followed the documentation that you have mentioned and i have apply the Custom Authorization Token policy and added the header policy in which i have added the header name "Custom" and the header value "the token" (the token is constant so i like to be passed automatically from the api manager and not to be set from the user) but the response like the attached screenshot is fail